# Exiting an infinite process in python subprocess

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, infinite

i have the following code

```
c = open("text.txt", 'a')    

output = subprocess.Popen('ping -t 127.0.0.1', stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

c.write(str(output))
```

But as the ping is infinite , the code stucks at line two till i close the cmd

how can i close the infinite subprocess

> i use python 2

Comment: I am using python 2

Comment: i found out the solution thanks @Saypy

Comment: process = subprocess.Popen('ping -t 127.0.0.1', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
time.sleep(10)
process.kill()
output=process.stdout.read()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use -n argument (in linux) for ping to set limited number of ping signals:

```
process = subprocess.Popen('ping -n 1 127.0.0.1', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = process.communicate()[0]
with open("text.txt", 'a') as f:
    f.write(str(output))
```

Or read a single first line only:

```
process = subprocess.Popen('ping 127.0.0.1', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

output = process.stdout.readline()
process.stdout.close()
process.kill()

with open("text.txt", 'a') as f:
    f.write(str(output))
```

Comment: process = subprocess.Popen('ping -t 127.0.0.1', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output=process.communicate()[0]
process.kill()   still the code get stuck

Comment: doesn't work ! process = subprocess.Popen('ping 127.0.0.1', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

output = process.stdout.readline()
process.stdout.close()
process.kill() print(output) prints nothing

Comment: and i need infinite ping only

Comment: i use python2 version not 3

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use `check_output` and add a `timeout`:

```
from subprocess import check_output

output = check_output('ping -t 127.0.0.1', timeout=seconds)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
process = subprocess.Popen('ping -t 127.0.0.1', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
time.sleep(10)
process.kill()
output=process.stdout.read()
```

with this code , subprocess runs and data will be given stdout,

we don't need to use communicate

when ever you want to stop the process,

use process.kill()

and get data using stdout.read()